# Async forEach , rearranged array in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am querying into my array and I get some results (10). I want for each time a use the query to get the same results , as these are my data for a tableView. But as I try to calculate the average rating for each , my table rearranges each time , as it is async. Can I keep the original sequence from query result?

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE `genres` = "'+genre+'" ORDER BY `movieId` DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET '+count+'', function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    result.forEach(function(movie) {
      getAverageRating(movie["movieId"],movie["title"], function (data) {
        dataModel.push({
          movieId: movie["movieId"],
          title: movie["title"],
          averageRating: data
        });
        if (dataModel.length==10) {
          response.send(dataModel);
        }
      });
    });
  });

function getAverageRating (movieId,movieTitle,callback) {

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM `ratings` WHERE `movieId` = ?',[movieId], function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    var sum = 0;
    result.forEach(function(movie) {
      sum += movie["rating"];
    });
    var data = (sum / result.length);

    callback(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Try `async.eachSeries`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select movies with average rating in one query, it will be faster and would not cause rearrangement. Use query like this:

```
SELECT m.movieId, m.title, AVG(rating) avg_rating
  FROM (SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY movieId DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10) m, ratings r
 WHERE m.movieId = r.movieId
 GROUP BY m.movieId, m.title
```

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner in sql , do I change my getAverageRating query or my initial ?

Comment: I used it instead of my initial query. I get the including avg_rating for each movie but the query needs 30+ seconds even with a LIMIT 10

Comment: `LIMIT` doesn't make query run faster. First of all, you need to check if you have indexes on field `movieId` in `ratings` table and on field `genres` in `movies` table. Than you can select only fields you need from movies table, see edit.

Comment: it runs in the entire table which is 10k movies , can I limit the request for 10 movies or so ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM movies m ... m must be outside of ( )

Answer (score 0):

You can set data to array using index

```
result.forEach(function(movie, i) {
    getAverageRating(movie["movieId"], movie["title"], function (data) {
        dataModel[i] = {
            movieId: movie["movieId"],
            title: movie["title"],
            averageRating: data
        });
```

Comment: I get random null results with this